# Is it possible to pin email from specific sender to be pin on top in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I get technology newsletter in my office mailbox in Outlook that I have pinned so every new email from same sender stays on top, I want to know if similarly of there exist any feature that can pin the email from specific sender on top ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to get gmail to show this one email at the top of the window is to use multiple inboxes. I am going to assume that the newsletter has the label "thenewsletter"

1. Go to settings/inbox
2. Change inbox type to multiple inboxes
3. Define the search query for section 1 to be "label:thenewsletter"
4. You can specify a small number for Maximim page size
5. Pick "above the inbox" for Multiple inbox position.
6. Don't forget to click save.

Now you will see above the main inbox a section that shows the most recent conversations/messages that meet the specified criteria.